# Can I download a book from a non amazon website and read it in my Amazon Kindle For Mac App?

Tags: macos, ebook, kindle

I want to download this [book](http://pragprog.com/book/mzcd/core-data) and read it using [Amazon Kindle for Mac](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&docId=1000423923&tag=googhydr-21&hvadid=7117634526&ref=pd_sl_3w4mmlywzr_b).

Is this possible or does Amazon Kindle for mac only allow books bought directly from Amazon store?

Comment: If you vote to close, please explain why. It's on how to load data into a certain desktop application and seems on-topic to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are fine buying that book. You want the ".mobi" for your Kindle.
From Amazon's website:

> [Files the Kindle recognizes:](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_navbox_recognize_200375630?nodeId=200375630&#recognize)
>  - Documents: Kindle (.AZW, .AZW1). Text (.TXT),   
>  - Unprotected Mobipocket (.MOBI, .PRC)  
>  - Audible: Audible (.AA, .AAX)
>  - Music: MP3 (.MP3)

Note that the popular ".epub" format is not there. Be careful because many books are in the ".epub" format.

Comment: I think they give you the mobi formatted file and you do need to access the Amazon website at all.

Comment: @JohnDR I didn't mean that. I fixed the formatting to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

It says you get the "mobi" Kindle format, just save that file to your "My Kindle Content" or the MAC version of that directory and you will have it on your Kindle app.

Comment: That's .mobi, not .modi.

Comment: @daviesgeek thanks for that very important typo correction.

Comment: And it's "Mac" not "MAC".  But we'll leave that one.. ;)

Comment: Yup, no problem. @techie007 :-)